# How to add 2nd columns together in 2 2d lists?

Tags: python, list, set, tuples

I have 2 lists of numbers in python as follows:

```
a = [ [1000,1], [2000,2], [3000,3] ]
b = [ [1000,5], [2000,6], [3000,7] ]
```

The first columns will always be identical.  I would like to add the second columns together to form a 3rd list c where:

```
c  =[ [1000,6], [2000,8], [3000,10] ]
```

I have tried doing this using list comprehensions, but I trouble getting the syntax right for using 2d lists.

Thanks

**edit:**
Ok, here was my best attempt at trying this.  I forgot the zip function:

```
c = [[x[0],x[1] + y[1]] for x,y in (a,b)]
```

Comment: Yep, just edited to include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list comprehension combined with the `zip()` function will do the trick:

```
c = [[aa[0], aa[1] + bb[1]] for aa, bb in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data structures look like they would work better as dictionaries, since the first elements in the sub-lists appear to function as keys. So to begin with, I'd suggest your data look like this:

```
a = {1000: 1, 2000: 2, 3000: 3}
b = {1000: 5, 2000: 6, 3000: 7}
```

One of the advantages of having more appropriately thought out data structures is, python will usually have a nice builtin to do what you're looking to do. In this case, the `collections` module is very helpful:

```
from collections import Counter
c = dict(Counter(a) + Counter(b))
```

Which gives you a c looking like this:

```
{1000: 6, 2000: 8, 3000: 10}
```

Answer (score 1):

If items are integers (or floats), you could use Numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

aa = np.array([[ 1000, 1 ],  [ 2000, 2 ], [ 3000, 3 ]])
bb = np.array([[ 1000, 5 ],  [ 2000, 6 ], [ 3000, 7 ]])
cc = np.array(aa)
cc[:,1] += bb[:,1]
```